# Kubuntu 22.04.2 boots into emergency mode, but only if no DVD is present

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, cd-drive

I have a computer with a DVD drive that is running Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64. To make it so that a disk would mount properly when inserting it into the CD-ROM drive, I made some changes to /etc/fstab. The line in question I added is `/dev/sr0   /media/cdrom   udf,iso9660   ro,auto,user,exec,utf8  0 0` (I have edited the amount of spaces to fit properly here if that matters).

As this is the only change I made to fstab, and the rather odd behavior of not being able to boot normally without a disk inside the drive, I'm 90% certain this line is causing it. However, I still want to be able to have the drive auto-mount when I put a disk in. How can I go about doing that, without needing a random disk laying around to boot?

Comment: I suspect that if you don’t have a DVD in the drive the system is hanging waiting to mount something. I don’t use DVDs now but if I remember correctly most systems will ask you if you want to mount removable media when you insert it. This may not be exactly what you want. Alternatively look at autofs. It can do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The `auto` in your `/etc/fstab` line ("`/dev/sr0   /media/cdrom   udf,iso9660   ro,auto,user,exec,utf8  0 0`") tells the system to `mount` the DVD at startup (when it does `mount -a`). As you've noticed, Linux `mount` doesn't handle "no DVD" well.

Remove the `auto` option.

Read `man fstab mount`.